# Omitting a convex hull in geom.convexhull in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've got a bunch of data with location information, which I'm plotting as a PCA. I've plotted convex hulls for the known location info using geom.convexhull with a colour assigned for each one, but for some of the data this info isn't known and it makes no sense to plot a convex hull with these data. Whatever I try, though, it insists on plotting a convex hull for all of these NA values. I've even tried setting the colour of this category to white or NULL, but I still get a grey convex hull.

Here is the code:

```
col.loc <-c("gold1","darkgoldenrod","coral4","firebrick2","chocolate3",NULL)
names( col.loc )   <- levels( location )
col.loc   <- col.loc[ match( location, names( col.loc ) ) ]

ggplot(PCs.test, aes(x=Comp1 ,y=Comp2,  fill = location) )+
  geom_convexhull(data = PCs.test, aes(x=Comp1, y = Comp2, fill = location), alpha = 0.2)+
  geom_point(data = PCs.patch, aes(x=Comp1, y = Comp2,colour = location, fill = location),fill = col.loc, colour = "black",shape = 21,  size=5)+
  labs(x = xlab, y= ylab)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = col.loc)+
  scale_colour_manual(values = col.loc)+
  theme_bw()
```

Does anyone have any suggestions of how I can remove this grey blob?

[image]

data:

````
0.01039394858538, -0.00932138894452528, 0.0325535388430693, -0.023375436185711, 
-0.00154900130339147, 0.0340142551190819, 0.0781245383485114, 
-0.147793081245623, -0.0330483040334001, 0.059025248022727, 0.0335519631243564, 
0.0477034324070876, -0.0715248424338567, -0.0260234800037971, 
-0.0380577792219177, -0.0463910255105573, -0.0256949056570816, 
-0.0425263971643931, -0.0509556729930634, -0.0246321865341547, 
-0.043519420090264, 0.0152017497470257, 0.0398986675154894, -0.050869842304147, 
-0.0150087516792891, 0.0934174157712665, 0.155912639191764, 0.0340276538470696, 
-0.0313166879635396, 0.0652913240682204, 0.0272261383293671, 
0.00286382582818958, 0.0176399741696046, 0.0412978335302015, 
-0.0476857740936087, 0.0320361236030713, -0.0348972752200948, 
-0.0320443594236757, 0.0371776342433834, -0.00439570174870682, 
-0.00496692290143357, -0.0329250922238096, 0.047195387337143, 
-0.0666364992095936, 0.0828282340926389, 0.0397486049864102, 
0.019841183549318, -0.0912494332361927, 0.0319584173657957, 0.0158025571614613, 
-0.0248636266724529, -0.0210971103758587, -0.0198029195939492, 
-0.0506716368038182, 0.0327105885898535, -0.00303512273873664, 
-0.0316843333971739, -0.00391950447033179, 0.0712057690523217, 
0.0215349029979596, 0.0026652469620278, 0.00986779255941438, 
-0.0319599106820346, -0.0404007479289159, 0.0166392446881513, 
-0.0380708660776105, 0.0465931388409596, 0.00522205197409137), 
    Comp2 = c(0.00422609507342881, -0.0162637307024865, 0.0156993130254523, 
    -0.0540323524142059, -0.00312349147681066, -0.01091725409822, 
    -0.0113444592817237, -0.0204629698600591, 0.0301493938196749, 
    0.02462009523297, 0.00737752584637478, 0.00911422986386769, 
    -0.00838193843695346, 0.00212785740172612, -0.0140543486259848, 
    0.0112700303997874, 0.00960140856133951, 0.0189953745760193, 
    0.00677616766942472, -0.0111340813499553, -0.00835999284779285, 
    -0.00339609571639809, 0.00164929801053823, 0.000462088658906684, 
    0.0184459489362376, 0.00469407478690591, -0.0385735220113072, 
    -0.0335112850428783, -0.011736161555394, 0.0208362555153905, 
    0.0177413631543652, -0.014528648350317, -0.021782245701082, 
    0.00401373432373146, 0.0180682502811386, 0.0412076889371237, 
    1.66683210580637e-05, -0.000510287171132948, 0.0155321272425612, 
    0.00541589435245292, 0.00662448594366603, 0.00889495640754264, 
    0.00968341368950365, -0.00709748860434205, -7.45703778430537e-05, 
    -0.00311663763095604, 0.0551373465649345, -0.0117210857783028, 
    0.0276334677479586, 0.00817166370543823, 0.00801017872471792, 
    -0.00302196990196178, 0.00575716842448092, -0.0063996181255583, 
    0.00603093189994672, 0.00238639153447097, 0.0121758145645393, 
    0.0139510046403071, -0.0267472389081686, -0.0734338528991655, 
    -0.0200840693577482, -0.0378637763411677, -0.0442810140454594, 
    0.000334255876245872, 0.0237647221961368, -0.0373877747006164, 
    0.0743167309035814, -0.00481953999679666, 0.00622950990942348, 
    0.0010185745874187), location = c("SA", "TZ", "NT", "NT", 
    "NT", "NT", "TZ", "SA", "NT", "SA", NA, NA, NA, "TZ", NA, 
    NA, "NT", "SA", "SA", "SA", "SA", "SA", "SA", "SA", "SA", 
    "SA", NA, NA, NA, "SA", "SA", "SA", "SA", "SA", "SA", "MM", 
    "SA", "SA", "SA", "TZ", "SA", "SA", "SA", "SA", "SA", "SA", 
    "SA", "SA", "SA", "SA", "SA", "SA", "ZM", "ZM", "ZM", "SA", 
    "SA", "SA", NA, NA, "MM", "MM", "MM", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA))```
````

Comment: Please share your data using `dput(df)`?

Comment: Instead of setting that value to white or NULL, try setting it to `NA`. It might work.

Comment: @Quinten, data added

I've tried NULL, NA and "white", and they all give the grey polygon